# Angular 2 Material Dialog box

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

I am making an application with Angular 2 and Angular Material 2 and on one of the pages I have to use a dialog box. I checked out the description and usage on the [MdDialog docs](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) but that didn't solve my problem with my dialog box.

What I want for my dialog box is that when I open the dialog box, it shows me a list and when I click on one of the element of the list it goes to more options of that list.

```
--------------
|  Heading   |
| Option 1   |
| Option 2   |    --->  ----------------
| Option 3   |          | <-- Option 1 |
| Option 4   |          |  Option 1    |
| Option 5   |          |  Option 2    |
| Cancel  Ok |          |  Cancel   Ok |
-------------           ----------------
```

So like it is showed in the design when I click Option 1 then it takes me to more options of Option 1. And all of this is in the dialog box. 
So how can I do this? Thanks!!

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a component in the dialog box that changes based on what the used clicked on. This way, you can open a dialog box, then the user can keep interacting with it, as the options inside it change. Then, you may close it, just like any `MdDialog`.